# React setInterval in useEffect with setTimeout delay

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval, use-effect

I want to run an interval with a delay for the first time it fires. How can I do this with useEffect? Because of the syntax I've found it difficult to achieve what I want to do

The interval function

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      //do something here
      return ()=> clearInterval(timer)
    }, 1000);
  },[/*dependency*/])
```

The delay function

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
//I want to run the interval here, but it will only run once 
//because of no dependencies. If i populate the dependencies, 
//setTimeout will run more than once.
}, Math.random() * 1000);
  }, []);
```

Sure it is achievable somehow...

Comment: `setInterval` already has a delay at the first time, do you need a different delay timeout than the interval period?

Comment: ionush, this is not a trivial problem. see my answer for explanation

Answer (score 7):

**getting started**

Consider detangling the concerns of your component and writing small pieces. Here we have a `useInterval` custom hook which strictly defines the `setInterval` portion of the program. I added some `console.log` lines so we can observe the effects -

```js
// rough draft
// read on to make sure we get all the parts right
function useInterval (f, delay)
{ const [timer, setTimer] =
    useState(null)
  
  const start = () =>
  { if (timer) return
    console.log("started")
    setTimer(setInterval(f, delay))
  }
  
  const stop = () =>
  { if (!timer) return
    console.log("stopped", timer)
    setTimer(clearInterval(timer))
  }
    
  useEffect(() => stop, [])
  
  return [start, stop, timer != null]
}
```

Now when we write `MyComp` we can handle the `setTimeout` portion of the program -

```js
function MyComp (props)
{ const [counter, setCounter] =
    useState(0)
    
  const [start, stop, running] =
    useInterval(_ => setCounter(x => x + 1), 1000) // first try
  
  return <div>
    {counter}
    <button
      onClick={start}
      disabled={running}
      children="Start"
    />
    <button
      onClick={stop}
      disabled={!running}
      children="Stop"
    />
  </div>
}
```

Now we can `useInterval` in various parts of our program, and each one can be used differently. All the logic for the start, stop and cleanup is nicely encapsulated in the hook.

Here's a demo you can run to see it working -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const useInterval = (f, delay) =>
{ const [timer, setTimer] =
    useState(undefined)
  
  const start = () =>
  { if (timer) return
    console.log("started")
    setTimer(setInterval(f, delay))
  }
  
  const stop = () =>
  { if (!timer) return
    console.log("stopped", timer)
    setTimer(clearInterval(timer))
  }
    
  useEffect(() => stop, [])
  
  return [start, stop, timer != null]
}
  
const MyComp = props =>
{ const [counter, setCounter] =
    useState(0)
    
  const [start, stop, running] =
    useInterval(_ => setCounter(x => x + 1), 1000)
  
  return <div>
    {counter}
    <button
      onClick={start}
      disabled={running}
      children="Start"
    />
    <button
      onClick={stop}
      disabled={!running}
      children="Stop"
    />
  </div>
};


ReactDOM.render
  ( <MyComp/>
  , document.getElementById("react")
  )
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

---

**getting it right**

We want to make sure our `useInterval` hook doesn't leave any timed functions running if our timer are stopped or after our components are removed. Let's test them out in a more rigorous example where we can add/remove many timers and start/stop them at any time -

[image: add/remove timers]

A few fundamental changes were necessary to make to `useInterval` -

```js
function useInterval (f, delay = 1000)
{ const [busy, setBusy] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // start
    if (!busy) return
    setBusy(true)
    const t = setInterval(f, delay)
    // stop
    return () => {
      setBusy(false)
      clearInterval(t)
    }
  }, [busy, delay])
  
  return [
    _ => setBusy(true),  // start
    _ => setBusy(false), // stop
    busy                 // isBusy
  ]
}
```

Using `useInterval` in `MyTimer` component is intuitive. `MyTimer` is not required to do any sort of cleanup of the interval. Cleanup is automatically handled by `useInterval` -

```js
function MyTimer ({ delay = 1000, auto = true, ... props })
{ const [counter, setCounter] =
    useState(0)
    
  const [start, stop, busy] =
    useInterval(_ => {
      console.log("tick", Date.now()) // <-- for demo
      setCounter(x => x + 1)
    }, delay)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("delaying...") // <-- for demo
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("starting...") // <-- for demo
      auto && start()
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  
  return <span>
    {counter}
    <button onClick={start} disabled={busy} children="Start" />
    <button onClick={stop} disabled={!busy} children="Stop" />
  </span>
}
```

The `Main` component doesn't do anything special. It just manages an array state of `MyTimer` components. No timer-specific code or clean up is required -

```js
const append = (a = [], x = null) =>
  [ ...a, x ]
  
const remove = (a = [], x = null) =>
{ const pos = a.findIndex(q => q === x)
  if (pos < 0) return a
  return [ ...a.slice(0, pos), ...a.slice(pos + 1) ]
}

function Main ()
{ const [timers, setTimers] = useState([])
  
  const addTimer = () =>
    setTimers(r => append(r, <MyTimer />))
    
  const destroyTimer = c => () =>
    setTimers(r => remove(r, c))
  
  return <main>
    <button
      onClick={addTimer}
      children="Add Timer"
    />
    { timers.map((c, key) =>
      <div key={key}>
        {c}
        <button
          onClick={destroyTimer(c)} 
          children="Destroy"
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </main>
}
```

Expand the snippet below to see `useInterval` working in your own browser. Fullscreen mode is recommended for this demo -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const append = (a = [], x = null) =>
  [ ...a, x ]
  
const remove = (a = [], x = null) =>
{ const pos = a.findIndex(q => q === x)
  if (pos < 0) return a
  return [ ...a.slice(0, pos), ...a.slice(pos + 1) ]
}

function useInterval (f, delay = 1000)
{ const [busy, setBusy] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // start
    if (!busy) return
    setBusy(true)
    const t = setInterval(f, delay)
    // stop
    return () => {
      setBusy(false)
      clearInterval(t)
    }
  }, [busy, delay])
  
  return [
    _ => setBusy(true),  // start
    _ => setBusy(false), // stop
    busy                 // isBusy
  ]
}

function MyTimer ({ delay = 1000, auto = true, ... props })
{ const [counter, setCounter] =
    useState(0)
    
  const [start, stop, busy] =
    useInterval(_ => {
      console.log("tick", Date.now())
      setCounter(x => x + 1)
    }, delay)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("delaying...")
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("starting...")
      auto && start()
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  
  return <span>
    {counter}
    <button
      onClick={start}
      disabled={busy}
      children="Start"
    />
    <button
      onClick={stop}
      disabled={!busy}
      children="Stop"
    />
  </span>
}

function Main ()
{ const [timers, setTimers] = useState([])
  
  const addTimer = () =>
    setTimers(r => append(r, <MyTimer />))
    
  const destroyTimer = c => () =>
    setTimers(r => remove(r, c))
  
  return <main>
    <p>Run in expanded mode. Open your developer console</p>
    <button
      onClick={addTimer}
      children="Add Timer"
    />
    { timers.map((c, key) =>
      <div key={key}>
        {c}
        <button
          onClick={destroyTimer(c)} 
          children="Destroy"
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </main>
}

ReactDOM.render
  ( <Main/>
  , document.getElementById("react")
  )
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

---

**getting advanced**

Let's imagine an even more complex `useInterval` scenario where the timed function, `f`, and the `delay` can change -

[image: advanced timers]

```js
function useInterval (f, delay = 1000)
{ const [busy, setBusy] = // ...
  const interval = useRef(f)

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = f
  }, [f])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // start
    // ...
    const t =
      setInterval(_ => interval.current(), delay)
      
    // stop
    // ...
  }, [busy, delay])
  
  return // ...
}
```

Now we can edit `MyTimer` to add the `doubler` and `turbo` state -

```js
function MyTimer ({ delay = 1000, auto = true, ... props })
{ const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  
  const [doubler, setDoubler] = useState(false) // <--
  const [turbo, setTurbo] = useState(false)     // <--
  
  const [start, stop, busy] =
    useInterval
      ( doubler   // <-- doubler changes which f is run
          ? _ => setCounter(x => x * 2)
          : _ => setCounter(x => x + 1)
      , turbo     // <-- turbo changes delay
          ? Math.floor(delay / 2)
          : delay
      )

  // ...
```

Then we add a <kbd>double</kbd> and <kbd>turbo</kbd> button -

```js
  // ...
  const toggleTurbo = () =>
    setTurbo(t => !t)
    
  const toggleDoubler = () =>
    setDoubler(t => !t)
  
  return <span>
    {counter}
    {/* start button ... */}
    <button
      onClick={toggleDoubler}  // <--
      disabled={!busy}
      children={`Doubler: ${doubler ? "ON" : "OFF"}`}
    />
    <button
      onClick={toggleTurbo}    // <--
      disabled={!busy}
      children={`Turbo: ${turbo ? "ON" : "OFF"}`}
    />
    {/* stop button ... */}
  </span>
}
```

Expand the snippet below to run the advanced timer demo in your own browser -

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } = React

const append = (a = [], x = null) =>
  [ ...a, x ]
  
const remove = (a = [], x = null) =>
{ const pos = a.findIndex(q => q === x)
  if (pos < 0) return a
  return [ ...a.slice(0, pos), ...a.slice(pos + 1) ]
}

function useInterval (f, delay = 1000)
{ const interval = useRef(f)
  const [busy, setBusy] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = f
  }, [f])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // start
    if (!busy) return
    setBusy(true)
    const t =
      setInterval(_ => interval.current(), delay)
      
    // stop
    return () => {
      setBusy(false)
      clearInterval(t)
    }
  }, [busy, delay])
  
  return [
    _ => setBusy(true),  // start
    _ => setBusy(false), // stop
    busy                 // isBusy
  ]
}

function MyTimer ({ delay = 1000, ... props })
{ const [counter, setCounter] =
    useState(0)
  
  const [doubler, setDoubler] = useState(false)
  const [turbo, setTurbo] = useState(false)
  
  const [start, stop, busy] =
    useInterval
      ( doubler
          ? _ => setCounter(x => x * 2)
          : _ => setCounter(x => x + 1)
      , turbo
          ? Math.floor(delay / 2)
          : delay
      )
      
  const toggleTurbo = () =>
    setTurbo(t => !t)
    
  const toggleDoubler = () =>
    setDoubler(t => !t)
  
  return <span>
    {counter}
    <button
      onClick={start}
      disabled={busy}
      children="Start"
    />
    <button
      onClick={toggleDoubler}
      disabled={!busy}
      children={`Doubler: ${doubler ? "ON" : "OFF"}`}
    />
    <button
      onClick={toggleTurbo}
      disabled={!busy}
      children={`Turbo: ${turbo ? "ON" : "OFF"}`}
    />
    <button
      onClick={stop}
      disabled={!busy}
      children="Stop"
    />
  </span>
}

function Main ()
{ const [timers, setTimers] = useState([])
  
  const addTimer = () =>
    setTimers(r => append(r, <MyTimer />))
    
  const destroyTimer = c => () =>
    setTimers(r => remove(r, c))
  
  return <main>
    <p>Run in expanded mode. Open your developer console</p>
    <button
      onClick={addTimer}
      children="Add Timer"
    />
    { timers.map((c, key) =>
      <div key={key}>
        {c}
        <button
          onClick={destroyTimer(c)} 
          children="Destroy"
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </main>
}

ReactDOM.render
  ( <Main/>
  , document.getElementById("react")
  )
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think What you're trying to do is this:

```js
const DelayTimer = props => {
  const [value, setvalue] = React.useState("initial");
  const [counter, setcounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    setTimeout(() => {
      setvalue("delayed value");
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setcounter(c => c + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Value:{value} | counter:{counter}
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<DelayTimer />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. One of the problems what I was using useState values within the setInterval closure and the values were stale, so I had to use the setState(latestState =>{}) latestState value //e.g. [state, setState] = useState("") to grab the latest state

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? the empty array on useeffect tells it will run this code once the element is rendered

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => {
  
  const [value,setvalue] = useState('initial')
  const [counter,setcounter] = useState(0)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setvalue('delayed value')
    setcounter(counter+1)
    clearInterval(timer)
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
  
  return(<div>
          Value:{value} | counter:{counter}
         </div>)
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SFC/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

Comment: No, I want to run a setInterval

Comment: I edited the snippet, check if it is what you want, i added a counter to check if the interval is stopped after using clearInterval

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a `setInterval` inside `useEffect`, I think you switched up the order a bit, it should be like this

```js
const INTERVAL_DELAY = 1000
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  /* do repeated stuff */
  }, INTERVAL_DELAY)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
})
```

The interval will start after a delay, so if you want an interval delay of X seconds to start after Y seconds, you have to actually use a delay in setTimeout as Y - X

```
const INITIAL_DELAY = 10000
const INTERVAL_DELAY = 5000

useEffect(() => {
  let interval
  setTimeout(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
    /* do repeated stuff */
    }, INTERVAL_DELAY)
  }, INITIAL_DELAY - INTERVAL_DELAY)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
})
```