# how to render react functional component after interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, functional-programming, render, intervals

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://......com/..../${id}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(serviceDetail);
        setServiceDetail(data);
      });
```

Note: I want it to render it after a certain time like every 5 seconds.(more or less)

Comment: What code you try to fix this issue ?

Comment: not to fix the issue. I want it to render after a certain time like 5 seconds.

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you want to call the api after every five second ?

Comment: yes , something like that.

Comment: Use settimeout inside useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it's helps

```
function App() {
  const [serviceDetail, setServiceDetail] = useState(0);

  const handleApiCall = () => {
    const url = 'https://......com/..../${id}';
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
      console.log(serviceDetail); setServiceDetail(data);
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    handleApiCall(); //for call api init time 
   
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleApiCall(); // call api after 5 seconds
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval); // clear interval after component unmounts.
  });

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: you need to `clearInterval` when the component unmounts. you can do this by returning a thunk, `() => { ... }` from `useEffect`. See [Effects with cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) in the docs

Answer (score 0):

The (currently) accepted answer misses an important detail. When the component unmounts, the interval will keep running. To stop it, you need to `clearInterval`. Another mistake is `useEffect` is called without dependencies. Here we use `useCallback` to generate a function that will only update when the `id` updates. Both the callback and the `id` are passed as dependencies to `useEffect` -

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(...)

const update = useCallback(id =>
  fetch(`http://.../${id}/`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(setData),
  [id]
)

useEffect(() => {
  const t = setInterval(_ => update(id), 5000)
  return () => clearInterval(t)
}, [update, id])
```

In a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61973691/633183) we introduce a custom `useInterval` hook that makes it easy for components to work with interval-based state. See the post for a fully functioning code demonstration.